# Dump (gdb) illegal number of block size

Tags: bash, memory, dump

I am trying to extract memory from a process and pass it on to a file but I am getting an error that I am not sure how to solve. I have looked around and it doesn't seem popular.

`sudo dump binary memory result.bin /proc/$pid/mem`

But then I get the following error.

`dump: illegal number of blocks per write -- memory`

I've tried changing the block size but not sure I am in the right direction. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I used the following that seemed to help:

```
dump b 10 ./test 0x0 0xf
```